# How to run method from string that shares object name

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, if-statement

So I have a list of objects that I want to detect in a user input, then execute methods on those objects mentioned.
My problem is I can extrapolate the strings equal to the object.name property, but I can't find a way to take that string and turn it into the object itself.

```js
// My constructor is "Interactable"

input.value = "Feed horse";

var o = "horse" //string achieved through other function in my program identifying the object of a sentence

function shouldIFeedIt() {
     for(l = 0; l < Interactable.length; l++) { //Interactable.length searches through every Interactable until it finds the one named "horse"
          if(Interactable[l] == o) {
               console.log(o); //This logs horse, but I can't turn this into the object upon which I want to run .feed()
               o.feed(); // horse.feed() prints text to the screen, but this does not...
          }
     }
```

So object.isight(); is the method I want to ultimately execute, but I can't figure out how to grab that paricular unit from Interactable[l].

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in order that we can better understand what your specific issue is. In other words, some sample input and expected results. We have no idea what your objects look like

Comment: Edited to make code more understandable. I hope that helps and I appreciate you responding at all

Comment: Not really. If it was clear you would have had more feedback and solutions by now

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want I think, Right?

```js
let Interactable = ["cat", "horse"];
let animals = {
  feed: (name) => {
    console.log("Currently feeding: " + name);
  },
};

let o = "horse";

function shouldIFeedIt() {
  for (l = 0; l < Interactable.length; l++) {
    if (Interactable[l] == o) {
      o = { ...animals, name: o };
      o.feed(o.name);
    }
  }
}

shouldIFeedIt();
```